# tkinter menu buttons greyed our after clicking them

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I am working on a simple word processor but every time I click an option in the file menu the options 'grey out' and cannot be clicked anymore. I have searched to find the answer why but I can't seem to find it anywhere else.
I'm using macOS 10.12.6 and Python 3.6.3, also my save function seems to be ignoring the 'if prevSaved == True' and skipping to the 'else:' (see code in hastags #)
Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import time

prevSaved = False
K = "Untitled"

def saveAs():
    text = textInput.get(1.0,END)
    filename = asksaveasfilename(title = "Choose where to save your file")
    file = open(str(filename) + ".txt" , "w+")
    file.write(text)
    file.close()
    prevSaved = True
    K, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))
    root.title("Python Word Processor - " + K)

#def save():
    #if prevSaved == True:
 #       text = textInput.get(1.0,END)
 #       file = open(str(filename) + ".txt" , "w")
 #       file.write(text)
 #       file.close()
 #   else:
 #       saveAs()

def opentxt():
    prevSaved = True
    filename = askopenfilename(title = "Choose the file to open", filetypes = (("txt files","*.txt"),("all files","*.*")))
    file = open(str(filename), "r")
    disptext = file.read()
    file.close()
    textInput.delete(1.0, END)
    textInput.insert(END, disptext)
    K, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))
    root.title("Python Word Processor - " + K)

root = Tk()                 #Creates the GUI called root            
root.resizable(False,False) #Makes the window non resizable
root.geometry('720x800')  #Makes the window 1280x720
root.title("Python Word Processor - " + K)
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
#Widgets - everything needs to have .pack() for it to show up, entries also need
#to have the pack.() on the line below o retrieve the information stored inside
#tkinter releif options - FLAT,RAISED,SUNKEN,GROOVE,RIDGE

f1 = Frame(root, width=720, height=50)
f1.pack(side=TOP)
f1.pack_propagate(0) #doesnt let its children control its size

mainmenu=Menu(root)
filemenu=Menu(mainmenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As", command = saveAs)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save")#, command = save)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command = opentxt)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

textInput = Text(root, width = 340, height = 770, font='bold')
textInput.

root.config(menu=mainmenu)
root.mainloop()
#widgets
#wID = Widget(root, widget_details)
```

Comment: First problem I see in your code is `textInput.`... You have not set it to be in the window yet. And this should throw an error. Who knows what it might break if it allows you to run the program. Outside of that one error I see I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. I can click anything on the file menu several times.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on Windows. The problem with `prevSaved` is that you didn't declare it `global prevSaved` at the beginning of the all the functions that set its value, so inside those functions it's considered a local variable by default. You don't need to declare a global variable to _reference_ its current value, but it must be declared in order to be able change its value (and not create a local variable that effectively hides the global one).